# Using kotlin coroutines in clean architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture, kotlin-coroutines, use-case

I am a beginner android developer. I'm just starting to learn clean architecture. Is it practical to have kotlin coroutines dependency in domain layer? As I know domain don't need have dependencies.

I want to use coroutine inside my UseCase class, but I don't know if it's right

Comment: Yes, it is OK to use any Concurrency tool / dependency in Domain layer. They are not like any 3rd party dependency, they are foundational tool (which is absolutely required considering raw Threads are not recommended), and most languages provide it in the language itself (C#, Python, Kotlin...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [developers.android documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices) says it is ok if you follow the caller's lifecycle. In almost every case, it is ViewModel. But still, you should call it from your ViewModel if you can.

Answer (score 1):

In my app, we are using that in the usecases, injected via Koin's DI. Viewmodels access usecases in order to run their function.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use suspend functions, because when you invoke it. On mvvm arquitecture, inside usecase this fuction will force you to use to run on a coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Domain layer should not depend on outside module like data layer or presenter layer, you can use a constructor parameter to inject to your usecase which is best approach and let other dependency library like dagger,hilt or koin handle the dependency for you.

- I recommend you read some book about clean architecture, you can get
  from [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=android%20clean%20architecture&i=stripbooks-intl-ship&crid=7Y87NJ2D7E8N&sprefix=android%20clean%20ar%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C191&ref=nb_sb_ss_fb_1_16).
- You can also get some practical guide on medium.

here is are sample

[Android clean architecture1](https://murainoyakubu.medium.com/practical-guide-to-building-powerful-and-easy-to-maintain-android-apps-with-clean-architecture-c6c8b592a0f2)

[Android clean architecture2](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/detailed-guide-on-android-clean-architecture-9eab262a9011)